# How do I make sure I don't accidentally hurt my cat while playing VR?

Tags: cats, safety

I have a small apartment. Sometimes I play virtual reality games by moving everything against the wall in my living room, giving me enough space to use the rest of the room to get the games to work.

I'm going to catsit for a friend starting next week. (This cat has lived with me before and we got along very well, so I'm looking forward to doing so again!) I'm nervous about playing VR while she's with me. I don't want to accidentally kick or step on her while I can't see, but my VR setup takes up most of the floor space in the cat's favorite room.

Am I overthinking this and it should be fine? Or are there things I need to do to make sure the cat is safe while I play? Should I consider not playing VR until the cat returns to live with my friend?

Comment: the best is if you can pause your gaming for now,there is a real risk the cat might get hurt when you are gaming,you and the cat can play a little real life game to compensate a little bit for your vr gaming.